# Windows and Windows Dual Boot sharing the whole file system

Tags: windows, partitioning, dualboot

I have a SSD drive on which I installed two version of the same Windows Server 2008. The way I installed them is the following:

- clone the original drive to a new one (just for safety)
- create an image of the original drive
- install a new WS2008 on the clone drive
- restore image of the original drive on the second partition

I can boot from boot partitions and they seem to working fine, however if I make a new file on OS1 I can see the same file on the OS2. If I remove an app on OS1 it will scramble the same app on the OS2. The idea is to have them operating separately.

I am not sure if the restore option scrambled the file system or need to edit entries in the boot manager.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zzdu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Windows uses internal addresses for physical disk that look like
`\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0` and `\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1`.
Many such addresses can be found in the registry to point
to disks and folders (`\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0\folder`).

To see the designations for your disks, use the command
`wmic diskdrive list brief`.

By cloning Windows, you have also cloned the registry.
What is happening is that even though you are booting from the second partition,
you are still using the first partition for many tasks that use such pointers
that are found in its registry.

In short, cloning is not a viable method for installing multiple versions of
the same operating system.

A better and safer method is installing Windows to the second partition from the
installation media.

Comment: I did install it from a new media and then restored the image. Is there a way to fix this? My problem is don't have all the drives for this pc and internet may not be an option.

Comment: Installing a new Windows instance is always the best option. Otherwise, some backup products can create an image and restore it to another partition or disk, so presumably making the necessary registry adjustments. You could try one such.

Comment: That's is what I have done. I have done a fresh installation of windows server and then used a backup created with windows backup manager to restore the image on the second partition.

Comment: The Windows backup manager is the worst, and is also discontinued. See [this list](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-drive-cloning-software.htm). I usually use AOMEI Backupper for disk imaging, but I never tried it in your scenario.